# Can't get a hidden div to toggle out JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

So i'm having trouble implementing a JQuery toggle on my navigation menu. I managed to do it quickly on a fresh file but cannot do it on my main version.

What I want: http://jsfiddle.net/wFN9t/6/
What I have: http://jsfiddle.net/KgCYE/9/

I know the div is hidden because If i remove #submenu li{display:none;} from the css, the submenu appears. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#submenu').click(function() {
 $('#submenu ul').toggle('');
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="aboutme.html"id="aboutme">Home</a></li>
    <li id="submenu"><a href="project.html" id="projects">Projects</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Design Exploration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work in progress</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Proposal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="reflections.html" id="reflections">Reflections</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#submenu ul{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea about putting `''` inside the `toggle()`?

Comment: You don't have jquery included in your main version.  That's why it isn't working, aside from the fact that you don't close your brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submenu').click(function() {
  $('#submenu ul').toggle('');
});
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#submenu').click(function() {
     $('#submenu ul').toggle('');
   });
});
```

And you should remove the `''` as it doesn't make the code clearer.

Also, don't forget to include jQuery when making a fiddle, using the menu in the left panel.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/6t5ne/)

Comment: Provided jquery is included, [their current code works](http://jsfiddle.net/u8wTZ/).

Comment: A simple mistake kept it from working? I didn't see any bugs in developer console

Comment: @user1803009 I find that odd.  I saw plenty of bugs.  $ isn't defined.  Unexpected end...

Comment: @user1803009 jquery wasn't included.